# Drawing Graphs (charts) in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, graph, draw

How can I draw dynamic graphs in web pages in JSF ?
People have suggested Google Chart Api

I want something that can work offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I found an answer to my question after scouring the net.
Apache myFaces has a tr:chart component that solves my problem :)

Answer (score 5):

[PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) have wonderful graph components. You can give them a try.

[Exadel Fiji](http://exadel.com/web/portal/fiji) also has nice graph components.

[MyFaces Trinidad](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/chart.html) is also an option (as indicated by the OP)

Answer (score 2):

if you use JSF 2, you can look at [flot4jsf2 project](http://code.google.com/p/flot4jsf2/). This is JSF2 component for drawing charts, it uses javascript flot library.

Comment: We recently used flot4jsf2 in a JSF2.2 project with good results though there's very little documentation and simplistic examples. Just have to make sure you import ALL the appropriate files into their relevant locations from the library package. Very easy to manipulate and use once up and running though.

Answer (score 1):

We were going through the same issue and ended up using JQPlot. It is extensive, JQuery based and so far so good.

http://www.jqplot.com/

Answer (score 0):

how about the new Canvas API? may be too bleeding edge to be counted on but it is functional in Chrome and Firefox, and looks to have a lot of potential.  Its API reminds of Quartz / OpenGL (but a lot simpler) which makes programatic drawing pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces provides a component to draw 2D graphics. 
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/paint2D.jsf

Answer (score 0):

I have used jfreechart to draw 3d and 2d Chart at run time.
I am using that graph on my pdf file as a report.
I will suggest you to use this jfreechart api,
I have attached some link for you please check it ,
Click here:

- [JFreeChart - An Introduction](http://www.roseindia.net/chartgraphs/jfreechart-introduction.shtml)
- [Create area chart in JSP page using JFreeChart](http://www.roseindia.net/chartgraphs/areachart-jsppage.shtml)

Second link is a example of jsp page with graph.

Comment: Honestly, roseindia.net sucks when it comes to "best practices". Practically all code examples over there are cluttered of bad practices. http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a Highcharts wrapper :

the demo is here : http://showcase-jsfcharts.rhcloud.com/