# Chart component for java server faces

Tags: java, jsf

Anyone know chart component for java server faces?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040296/drawing-graphs-in-jsf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trinidad chart control](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_chart.html) or [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Answer (score 2):

I use JFree chart library.

Comment: That was already mentioned by Padmarag :) Just upvote his answer instead of duplicating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSFCharts : https://github.com/yanLanglois/jsfcharts

The demo is here : http://showcase-jsfcharts.rhcloud.com/home.jsf

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://www.highfaces.org which also wraps HighCharts but uses a declarative approach and works with pure JSF Tags and Java Collections at the bean side rather than requiring to create a dedicated model.