# Any API support child have two or more parent in Tree or Graph?

Tags: java, jsf, zk

I am trying to create a graph or Tree something like below

```
             Start
               |
             Step1
            /        \
     Step2.1       Step2.2
           \           /
             Step3
```

Will this support by Tree component of JSF or ZK Framework or any third party API support this kind on scenario . I tried with this [ORG Charts](https://github.com/huangnoah/zkorgchart) but its not possible any other such API can help me to design such kind of thing.

Comment: Definitely a graph, trees are acyclic by definition. This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040296/drawing-graphs-charts-in-jsf